# Consuming a Jira REST API

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, jira-rest-api

I would like to consume a Jira REST API, but have been unsuccessful.

The Jira site gives the following request URL:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

And this is the json array, which is located on a file called collector.json:

```
"fields": [
            {
                "project":
                        {
                            "key": "ATL"
                        },
                "summary": "REST ye merry TEST.",
                "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
                "issuetype": {
                                "name": "Task"
                             }
            }
        ]
```

}

The following is the code:

```
<?php
include_once "collector.php";

$jiraValues = jsonArray("collector.json");
$jira_url = "http://jira.howareyou.org:8091/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta";
$jiraString = json_encode($jiraValues);

$request = curl_init($jira_url); // initiate curl object
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jiraString); // use HTTP POST to send form data
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $jira_url);

$json_raw = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $json_raw

curl_close($request); // close curl object

// This line takes the response and breaks it into an array using the specified delimiting character
$jira_response = json_decode($json_raw, TRUE);

print_r($jira_response);
```

When I run it, Nothing happens. I get no feedback.

I found it [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue), and replaced the information with my valid information.

Comment: Do you get a response from the `cURL` req ? also just try printing `$json_raw` for debugging

Comment: And ` more thing, use `echo` the JSON back to the caller instead of `print_r`

Comment: @Pogrindis i tried to echo it, still no result.  I am not sure what needs to be substituted in that cURL req. Its my first time dealing with it

Comment: Why are you using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. This request should be GET

Comment: @Dmitry Do you possibly have an example I can use ? For beginners

Comment: No, i haven't. But you can try `json_decode(file_get_contents($jira_url))` - and print result. Or try to open this uri in browser.

Comment: @Dmitry addIssue is a `POST` IE *("http://jira.howareyou.org:8091/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta")

Comment: @Pogrindis Yes, but in example uri `$jira_url = "http://jira.howareyou.org:8091/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta";` and it's GET.

Comment: If you want make POST - add `CURLOPT_POST, 1`

Comment: @Dmitry let me try that. thanks

Comment: But as better solution - https://github.com/madmis/jira-api (or any other lib.)

Comment: Does the CURL command you posted work for you?

Comment: @jannis, the curl command only works when I try it directly on the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Firstly define some helpful globals to help :

```
define('JIRA_URL', 'http://jira.howareyou.org:8091');
define('USERNAME', '');
define('PASSWORD', '');
```

Then we need to define a post method :

```
function post_issue($data) {
    $jdata = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => JIRA_URL . '/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta' . $resource,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => USERNAME . ':' . PASSWORD,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jdata,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result);
}
```

Then how we want to use it is like so :

Create a new issue

```
$new_issue = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'project' => array('key' => 'TIS'),
        'summary' => 'Test via REST',
        'description' => 'Description of issue goes here.',
        'priority' => array('name' => 'Blocker'),
        'issuetype' => array('name' => 'Task'),
        'labels' => array('a','b')
    )
);
```

Call our previously made function passing in the new issue :

```
$result = post_issue($new_issue);
if (property_exists($result, 'errors')) {
    echo "Error(s) creating issue:\n";
    var_dump($result);
} else {
    echo "New issue created at " . JIRA_URL ."/browse/{$result->key}\n";
}
```

A basic example of posting a new issue via REST

**Note:** The Jira API URL may need to be configured slightly

Comment: data would be the json array ?

Comment: @kya yes indeed, updated ! If you are passing in direct JSON array do not use the `$new_issue` var

Comment: I get the following errors now: Array to string conversion on this line CURLOPT_URL => JIRA_URL . '/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta' . $resource,  and the following error: Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class on this line: if (property_exists($result, 'errors'))

Comment: @kya remove `$resource` from the function input in `post_issue` also as you are passing in JSON 'as is' you will not need to re-encode it in the `post_issue` function.